# Bootstrap tree view: tree is not displaying

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-treeview

I'm new to Bootstrap-treeview (bootstrap-treeview.js v1.0.2). I'm trying to display the tree given in the docs, but it doesn't show up.

I've checked the 2 files, didn't spot the mistake.

html:

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap-treeview.min.css' %}">

        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="tree"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-ivk71nXhz9nsyFDoYoGf2sbjrR9ddh+XDkCcfZxjvcM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'bootstrap-treeview.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'functions.js' %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

functions.js

```
function getTree() {
  var tree = [
      {
        text: "Parent 1",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "Child 1",
            nodes: [
              {
                text: "Grandchild 1",
              },
              {
                text: "Grandchild 2",
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            text: "Child 2",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "Parent 2",
      }
    ];
  return tree;
}

$('#tree').treeview({data: getTree()});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating array `tree`, but returning `data` in the `getTree` function

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still get nothing, I've updated the code

Comment: What do you need exactly? I'm following the example of the treeview doc.

Comment: @saikuron I need to see what exactly do you have (and what does the debug console say)

Comment: Ok, I've fixed the pb: I put bootstrap.js cdn before jquerry cdn. Thanks for trying to help me :)

Comment: @saikuron I havent even noticed it :D Always check console for errors